# How to specify custom JRE path for Apache Tomcat in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, configuration, intellij-idea

The question is how to specify custom `JRE` path for `Apache tomcat` in `Intellij IDEA` (when starting an application from `IDEA`)?

It seems, that just configuring its path (path to `jvm.dll`) in `Apache Tomcat` monitor doesn't help. Are any other ideas or ways how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right way is:

1. Go to run configuration of Tomcat launching in IDEA
2. Select "Startup/Connection" tab
3. Select desired run mod ("Run"/"Debug"/....)
4. add new enviroment variable:

"JRE_HOME" with path to needed JRE.

See picture below:

[image]