# Apache Tomcat 7 - war file doesn't deploy

Tags: apache, tomcat, intellij-idea

In my web application project I use intellij idea and run apache tomcat 7 through it. I already set the path variable to tomacat bin as `CATALINA_HOME`. When I run it, the server is unable to deploy the war file. The last message that I can see in the idea is `INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\webapps\manager`.

I found the issue. When I run the tomcat7 with intellij idea, JRE_HOME is taken as the JDK path in the machine

```
Using JRE_HOME  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"
```

But when I run the tomcat7 with command prompt it shows
`Using JRE_HOME  "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"` and deploy the war file successfully

So how can I set the jre path in intellij idea and solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ 13 introduced a new option named `Use alternative JRE` in the `Server` tab of your Tomcat run configuration. For previous versions, you can still [override the `JRE_HOME` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20090939/500478).

Not sure this is the real cause of your problem, though...